# Do we influence our emotions or do our emotions influence us?

Tags: emotions

The activities that we choose can influence our emotions such as doing a fun activity will make you happy, but our emotions also make us choose our actions such as a breakup could make you angry. Is one more likely than the other or are they equal?

Comment: There are some interesting questions about the relationship of rationality and emotions already on this SE.